# Asynchronous tasks in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I have a Website (on Azure) where you can trigger asyncronous jobs, that needs a lot of traffic (copy files from one location to another).

So you press a button on the site and then I want to trigger a new job. What would be the best solution?

Solution 1) Use web jobs. But then there may problems with huge traffic, so that the website will not be reachable.

Solution 2) Use cloud service. Is it a good solution to start a new instance for each job? The jobs will not need a lot of cpu usage, but the traffic will be the point.

Solution 3) Is there any solution on azure, where you can just trigger a job, and ervery time it is triggered, a new instance will start, do the job and shutdown. Like fire and forget?

Comment: Here's relevant information about network bandwidth limits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626949/questions-about-azure-instance-allocated-bandwidth Network seems to be your primary resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a job message in an Azure Storage queue. Use an Azure Cloud Service worker role to consume the message and do whatever processing needs to be done.

Comment: But how should I scale? As far as I know there is no scaling on traffic.

Comment: You can autoscale based on queue length - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/06/26/autoscaling-windows-azure-applications/