# Is network bandwidth on Azure Web Sites different from Virtual Machines?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

From answers to other questions (such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626949/questions-about-azure-instance-allocated-bandwidth)), it sounds like different instance sizes offer different network throughput. My processing is I/O bound, and I'm trying to use web jobs to do it on a web site instance. Do web sites offer the same bandwidth as VMs with the same size/price point? Or if I need bandwidth higher than 100 Mb/sec, would I need to choose a solution other than web sites to do this processing?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the bandwidth limits are not currently exposed.
At the end of the day, Azure App Service is using some Cloud Services machines and the bandwidth should be quite similar than in Web/Worker roles.
However, the requests go through different mechanisms (IIS ARR for example) but it might not add so much overhead.

That being said, the best way would be to try and scale out (using multiple instances) if you need more.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the question open for a bit to see anyone happens to know how closely bandwidth on web sites aligns with the equivalent size/price VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @dmatson answer a small detail - right now, expect SLA for high availability, which means that you can have different numbers sometimes. You will need to wait for the official release of SLA - or scale out by the size or amount. The very good FAQ i have found on that topic is here, many networking-related questions are covered.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/09/28/my-personal-azure-faq-on-azure-networking-slas-bandwidth-latency-performance-slb-dns-dmz-vnet-ipv6-and-much-more/